# Generate a document template from a library of content blocks

Tags: xml, ms-word

My company has a collection of Word templates for different types of quotes. There are three main types, with the "firm quote" being the most detailed. Each of these templates follows the same general outline and is populated with the same boilerplate, with a few differences from one document to another.

Within the firm quote category, there are more boilerplate sections that can be added depending on the product being quoted.

What I would really like to do is create a library or database where each boilerplate section is tagged, and all of my templates pull from that same library. So ideally the user would step through a little menu and choose a quote type, and any additional boilerplate, and a template would be generated that they could then customize. If we were to update one boilerplate section, we wouldn't have to do it in two other locations.

I'm open to learning new software or coding languages for this, or even moving completely away from Word. I prefer to not look at any expensive software that can do all this for me; I'd much rather spend some time learning to do it myself.

Any idea how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I used to work for a company which developed a product which did exactly what you want. If you're interested in this software let me know and I'll add the product link.

So you have different options to do this:

- Buy such a product which would handle that for you. Since you're looking for a "non expensive software" it's maybe the wrong approach
- You can develop a Microsoft Word Plugin and manage a database with quotes or instead of a database it's also possible to manage simple Word files with the quotes as content and insert them to the users selection. The plugin you can create with Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition with C# or VB.NET
- You can develop a Microsoft Word Macro in VBA and create what you need in there.
- You can have a look at the Microsoft Word inbuilt function `Quick Parts`. You would probably need to distribute the quick parts among the users. I'm not too familiar with this inbuilt function. Look for more information here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Quick-Parts-and-AutoText-in-Word-7a527697-058f-4967-b8f1-aae0774e4813

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd like to look into the software you mentioned; could you add that link?

Comment: I learned their website is only in german. But they kindly provided me an english flyer (docugate.ch/flyer_en) about the software. Feel free to contact them (also in english).